# How can I ask the user to enter a lottery ticket number separated by a comma (e.g. 1,34,32,22,8,10), and store it in C?

Tags: c

I want to ask the user to enter a lottery ticket number (1-49 is the range and can't be more than 6 numbers entered) and I want to save it. I figured I could use an array. I'm just starting with C programming so I'm not sure. This is what I have so far. (I will then have to compared the entered number with a winning number and display the results.)

```
int n,i;
int tickentNum[n]; //ticket number will be entered by user
int winNum [n];//this is the winning number

printf("Your 6 numbers of ticket  must be entered separated by a comma: 
and the tens digit MUST NOT be 0. \n");
printf("E.g. 1,2,4,21,22,18\n");

printf("Please enter your ticket number:___\n");
scanf("%d,",&ticketNum[i]);
```

Comment: If you just want to store six numbers (for the lottery) you could as the user to enter them, one at a time. Or - if the whole lottery number has to be entered in a single line, divided by commas - you could go with something like this: scanf("%u,%u,%u,%u,%u,%u", tickentNum, tickentNum+1, tickentNum+2, tickentNum+3, tickentNum+4, tickentNum+5)

Comment: Recommend `char line[64];` then read the line with `fgets()`. Now parse the values from line with `sscanf()` validating the return, e.g. `if (sscanf (line " %d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d", &ticketNum[0], &ticketNum[1], &ticketNum[2], &ticketNum[3], &ticketNum[4], &ticketNum[5]) == 6) { /* now compare with winNum */ }`. You should also avoid using VLAs and `#define NVALUES 6` and declare your arrays with `int ticketNum[NVALUES];`, etc.

Comment: But both won't check if the user wants to (hor actually has) entered more numbers. Or with a leading 0. So if you want to be thoroughly, you will have to store the user input in a string and validate it either with something like regular expressions ... our you build yourself a function to check and interpret the user input yourself.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your thoughts. I will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have the assigned the array as tickentNum. For the winNum why have you initialised an array? This will give you n winNum places. Also you have to give the variable a value before using it and since you said n shouldn't be greater than 6 set it to 6. And for the last line I think you were trying to use a for loop but you have named them wrong so it wasn't working.

Comment: Ok, got it! Thanks! Yeah, I am working on the loop somewhere after this part. I appreciate your help.